# On scroll down load data dyanamicaly in cgridview yii

Tags: php, jquery, yii, yii-extensions

In `yii` i am using `Cgridview` widget with pagination. Instead of that i need to load the data dynamically by scroll down event. Is there any extension?

This is the widget i am using.

```
<?php 
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'leave-approve-grid',
'itemsCssClass'=>'table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped dataTable',
'filter'=>$model,
'dataProvider'=>$model->approve_search(),
'enablePagination' => true,    
'pagerCssClass'=>'dataTables_paginate paging_bootstrap table-pagination',
'pager' => array('header'=>'','htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pagination')),
'columns' => array(             
            array(name=>'type_id', 'value'=>'$data["leave_type"]','header'=>'Leave type','filter'=>CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,'type_id',CHtml::listData($model->SelectAllLeaveType(),'type_id','type'),array('prompt'=>'All'))),
            array(name=>'staff_name','value'=>'$data["staff_name"]','header'=>'Staff Name'),
),
)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, Yii gridview does not have any option for **smart rendering**. You should use **jquery data grid plugins** that have this feature. I have used [jqGrid plugin](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) and this is a very good data grid that has this feature and so many other features.

Comment: is there any other method?.do you have the working code of CGridview  using jqgrid plugin.?

Comment: CGridview can not integrate with jqgrid! These two plugins is completely different. If you need to use advanced features like smart rendering, you should leave CGridview completely and use jqgrid plugin. jqgrid is an easy to setup plugin and has simple documentation. Also many questions and answers exists in stackoverflow about it. So you can easily find the answers in case of probable problems.